# Why do I get 'No -renderInContext: method found' warning?

Tags: iphone, ios

I get a compiler warning at the -renderInContext:

```
- (UIImage *) imageFromView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img; 
}
```

I have QuartzCore in the project frameworks, and the code works.
How do I fix the code so it stops giving me the warning?

The exact warning I get is

```
warning: no '-renderInContext:' method found
warning: (Messages without a matching method signature
warning: will be assumed to return 'id' and accept
warning: '...' as arguments.)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try importing the Quartz framework into your application.

Then add,

`#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

to your application.

Comment: @Altaveron, Can you elaborate? I suggest opening a separate SO question if you have a specific concern.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it's due to the fact that the `CALayer` class header is in the QuartzCore framework.

In Xcode, in the Frameworks group, add the QuartzCore framework and it should be all fine.

Then, see [my post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032818/adding-core-data-to-existing-iphone-project/2032912#2032912) for how to include the header files in every source file. Now it's not for Core Data, but for QuartzCore (in the exact same way)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have QuartzCore.framework in your project?