# create CGImage from UIView Subclass

Tags: core-graphics, cgcontext, cgimage

How do I create a CGImage from UIView Subclass?

Should I use renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() to create a CG image from a view (subclass of UIView) that contains a drawing (core graphics via drawRect method)?

I have an view, myView, in which I am doing some drawing. I want to do some other core graphics operations with the drawing I have created - like blend modes etc with imported photos, so I need to get a CGimage from myView I assume. Not finding a CGImage property (my first guess). Poking around I found the solution below, but my subclass "does not declare the selector renderInContext", so I get an error.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.bounds.size);
[myView renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGImageRef cgImage = image.CGImage;
```

Comment: Similar question: [Why do I get 'No -renderInContext: method found' warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770544/why-do-i-get-no-renderincontext-method-found-warning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-renderInContext:` is a method on `CALayer`, not `UIView`.

Do this instead:

```
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

You will also need to import the headers for `CALayer`:

```
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

And link your app against the `QuartzCore` framework.