# Adding core data into existing iOS project

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding Core Data to existing iPhone project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032818/adding-core-data-to-existing-iphone-project)

how can I add core data into an existing iOS project? I added the data model file, created the data models from it and added the three properties into my app delegate all into my existing(!) project. I also added CoreData into the frameworks.

In my app delegate's didFinishLaunching-method I call [self managedObjectContext], but it returns nil. I guess I have to override the getter methods and load my data model from there? How do I do that?

Comment: This has already been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2032818/730701) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6821719/730701).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to create a new project (Empty project) and make sure Core Data is added in.  Then, just look over the differences, there should be four big ones:

1. Add in all the stuff that is created in the AppDelegate
2. Add in the Core Data framework
3. Add your data object
4. Modify the pch file