# Use of Core Data in iOS

Tags: ios, json, cocoa-touch, sqlite, core-data

I have been through a couple of these answers here, but I don't think I get it right..

I have several NSArray made of JSON requests. I want to store everything in the app instead of requesting the data all the time, and I understand I should use Core Data for this.

The problem is, I don't know how to initialize this.. I have tried to read up, but I have realized it will take a long time to understand this by just reading the class reference etc.

I have added an .xcdatamodel and created an entity with attributes identical to the data in one of the json object. How can I access the file for extracting and inserting information? I plan on parsing my whole json object into this file, but how can I instantiate the entity? Which delegates and where?

All tutorials I have watched had an option when they created the project, like "Use Core Data" or something, which when checked created lots of code automatically. I don't have that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might wanna go through some SO links: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032818/adding-core-data-to-existing-iphone-project). Also, I once remember going through [this guide](http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2009/12/adding-core-data-existing-iphone-projects/) for adding Core Data to my project. It might help you to go through [this link](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/06/02/saving-json-to-core-data/) for saving JSON to Core Data directly. I recommended this link here in SO a couple of times. Trust me, all this pain you are enduring setting up Core Data is well worth it when you see things starting to work!

Comment: Also, google for "Adding Core Data to existing projects" if you need more direction towards augmenting CD in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the core data stack. You can create a new, core data project, and get the core data elements added to the app delegate specifically for core data. You will have 3 properties, and one method. Just copy/paste the declaration and implementation of these elements to your app delegate. Make sure the managedObjectModel method and the persistentStoreCoordinator method are using your actual model name.

To work with core data, you need to read the core data documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

You will have to create entities to represent your data, the properties for the entities, and so fort. Get started with your project, read the documentation, and get started. You will have more questions which you will either ask or find here, but at least you got enough to get started.