# How do add core data to an existing project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding Core Data to existing iPhone project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032818/adding-core-data-to-existing-iphone-project)

Initially i have created project with out selecting coreData. After some point of development i want to use core data for data management. It's giving some exception like

```
context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init]; 
CDAlbum *albumInfo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CDAlbum" inManagedObjectContext:context]; 
albumInfo.albumName = @"MyAlbum"; 
CDPage *pageInfo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CDPage" inManagedObjectContext:context]; 
pageInfo.message = @"It's my message"; 
pageInfo.pageId = @"123456"; 
pageInfo.album = albumInfo;
albumInfo.page = pageInfo;
```

`'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'CDAlbum'`

I think this is because of linking. How can I resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: can you share your code for creating persistent store coordinator, managedobjectmodel and managedobjectcontext

Comment: @SunilPandey : context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    CDAlbum *albumInfo = [NSEntityDescription
insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CDAlbum"
 inManagedObjectContext:context];

    albumInfo.albumName = @"MyAlbum";
    CDPage *pageInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CDPage"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];

    pageInfo.message = @"It's my message";
    pageInfo.pageId = @"123456";
    
    pageInfo.album = albumInfo;
    albumInfo.page = pageInfo;

Comment: I think you should learn some basic concept of core Data. http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started check this

Answer (score 0):

1) Add CoreData frame in your project.
2) `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` in your `App_Prefix.pch` file. See [this accepted answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2032912/869455)