# Connect iOS app to Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm a beginner on iOS development, and I want to explose some sample app's development.

My question is if it's a good practice to build something, and figure out how to save data after building some project, or it have to be part of the development process?

Comment: this depend on your project, if the data a fundamental part of your app or it is just a plus?, if it is a plus you can implement it later on, but in general, I think you should think about it from the beginning of the development process

Comment: Got it. Basically I dont have a specific case in mind, just wanted to know if it's possible to try build something and then figure out the saving data aspect of the project @tkanzakic

Comment: yes, it is possible, if you plan to use Core Data is easiest to add it from the beginning, but you will find many information about how to accomplish this in a later stage of your development process

Comment: and you always have the option of use something different to Core Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depend on your project, is the data a fundamental part of your application or it is just a plus?, if it is a plus you can implement it later on, but in general, I think you should think about it from the beginning of the development process.

If you plan to use Core Data as the persistent storage it is easiest to add it from the begging, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032818/adding-core-data-to-existing-iphone-project) you can find how to add it in a later stage of your development process.