# Access Core Data From Previous iOS Application in new PhoneGap Application

Tags: ios, core-data, cordova, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an existing iOS application that I am in the process of rewriting.  The new implementation is using web technologies and PhoneGap for native functionality.

This new implementation will update/replace the existing application.

In my new PhoneGap application I need to access the core data that the previous application wrote.  So far I have made sure that the app ID on the new application is identical to the app ID on the previous application.  I have copied the .xcdatamodeld folder from the old app to the new app, and added the core data framework to my new app.

My issue is that I cannot seem to access a managed object context from the PhoneGap plugin.

In my existing application I get the managedObjectContext from the AppDelegate, but I don't see how that object is created/initialized.

Where does the managedObjectContext come from?  Where is it initialized?

Is there a project setting that I am missing?

Am I taking the wrong approach?

Comment: I haven't used PhoneGap but... if you have the code for `AppDelegate`, and if you're getting a managed object context from it, either (a) the code is in there somewhere or (b) some other class is creating it and handing it off to the `AppDelegate`. Look for a line that allocates an `NSManagedObjectContext` instance.

Comment: Thanks Tom this helped. I had neglected to add the Core Data stack code to my PhoneGap projects app delegate.  Now that I have done that my new application is reading the core data from my previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up needing to do was to add the core data stack code from my previous app delegate to my new app delegate.

[Adding Core Data to existing iPhone project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032818/adding-core-data-to-existing-iphone-project/2032912#2032912) helped point me in the right direction